# How to best handle different number formats in Mat in own functions

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

When writing own functions with OpenCV which are accessing single pixel values with `img.at<uchar>(y,x)`, `img.at<float>(y,x)`, ..., the input matrix has to be in the correct format. I could imagine some different approaches to make such a function able to handle different types of `Mat`.

1. Convert `src` to the correct format prior doing something else. This could lead to some loss of information in the case of "downgrading" the number space or some loss of effiency in the case of "upgrading" (if I get it right). But maybe converting to `CV_64U` is still very effective?
2. Creating a whole function for every type of input matrix seems to be not very elegant, but as I'm new to C++ I'm maybe not used to it.
3. Create if-else statements to distinguish between the types of `Mat` within the function itself.

Are there some other methods I'm not aware of? Is there a method which is best in terms of effiency, coding elegance and effort?

Here is a little example function:

```
myfoo(const Mat& src, Mat& dst)
{
    dst = src.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < dst.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < dst.cols; j++)
        {
            dst.at<uchar>(i, j) = i * j;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use template function. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template

Try this:

```
template <class T>
myfoo(const Mat& src, Mat& dst)
{
    dst = src.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < dst.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < dst.cols; j++)
        {
            dst.at<T>(i, j) = i * j;
        }
}
```

you can call it using `myfoo<uchar>(src, dst)`